# Python value_count() logical operator

Tags: python, pandas, function

So, I need the number of people with >1 with the user id but it gives true or false results.

```
user_id
ab23fae164e34af0a1ad1423ce9fd9f0
15a84e8951254011b47412fa4e8f65b8    
ffb82fda52b041e4b9af9cb4ef298c85
bd4a8b3e3601427e88aa1d9eab9f4290
f52ad1c7e69543a9940c3e7f8ed28a39
...
...
Code
risk = df.user_id.value_counts()
risk 

Output
2df96cd3537d415a9e7f23f419197187    6
6eeb7dbdf1fa4e7c95413bc0608dd21c    6
3b0a8e16846b4d779c5ba9e5499391af    5
.....
3b0a8e16846b4d779c5ba9e5499391af    1

Code:
risk = df.user_id.value_counts() > 1
risk 

Output
2df96cd3537d415a9e7f23f419197187     True
6eeb7dbdf1fa4e7c95413bc0608dd21c     True
3b0a8e16846b4d779c5ba9e5499391af     True
.....
6eeb7dbdf1fa4e7c95413bc0608dd21c     False
3b0a8e16846b4d779c5ba9e5499391af     False
```

Instead of true and false, I just need the number of users with > 1 occurrence of user id

Hope I make sense?

Comment: `sum(df.user_id.value_counts() > 1)` will do what you need. `True` is interpreted as 1, `False` is interpreted as a 0 and therefore summing the boolean column gives you the result you want

Answer (score 0):

We can chain them into one line

```
df.user_id.value_counts().loc[lambda x : x>1].sum()
```